# Split function-like macro call between two source files

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

Is there anything in the C Standard preventing me of doing the following?

```c
// main.c
#define DECORATE(x) ***x***
#include "call_macro.h"
this is the text I want decorated)
```

```c
// call_macro.h
DECORATE(
```

When running it though `gcc -E main.c`, I expected to get

```c
*** this is the text I want decorated***
```

Instead, it complained about `macro_call.h:2: error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "DECORATE"`, but I can't actually find any prohibition of it in the standard.

Thoughts?

Comment: Clang does not complain. Can’t test GCC in Godbolt, unless it has some way to provide a user-defined header file. Is anybody testing this with GCC?

Comment: I'm quite confident that there's a rule _somewhere_ that says that a macro invocation may not begin in an included file and continue into the file that included it, but I looked through 6.10 myself and couldn't find it, which might mean it's hiding in DR responses and never got incorporated into the text of the standard (as of N1570 anyway).  Hopefully someone else can give a more definitive answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I get an identical error message to OP with gcc 11.  I am very surprised to see clang accept this, it's usually even pickier than gcc.

Comment: (By the way, OP, don’t do that. If you do, a mob will show up at your door with pitchforks and torches.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger note taken. Removed the c99 tag

Comment: @EricPostpischil https://wandbox.org/permlink/eIow57WhlO6gP3Gr

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since Clang does not complain on constraint violation, is there a corresponding Clang issue (on GitHub)?

Comment: Created: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56890.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **5.1.1.2 Translation phases**
> (1.4) Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and `_Pragma` unary operator expressions are executed... A `#include` preprocessing directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1
> through phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

I believe this says that each included header is preprocessed separately, before being "merged" into the overall translation unit. It is at this point that an incomplete function-like macro invocation would be ill-formed:

> **6.10.3/4** ... There shall exist a `)` preprocessing token that terminates the invocation.

Comment: And 6.10.3/4 is a constraint. And violation of it requires a diagnostics.

Comment: However, the 6.10.3/4  does not say _where exactly_ a `)` preprocessing token shall exist. In the OP's code a `)` preprocessing token exists. Hence, Clang does not complain.

Answer (score 4):

This ...

> ```
> #define DECORATE(x) ***x***
> ```

... is a complete definition of function-like macro `DECORATE` (C17 6.10.3/10).  Its scope is the remainder of the translation unit (there being no corresponding `#undef`; C17 6.10.3.5/1) including source and header files `#include`d into that portion of the translation unit.

For it to be possible for the text of an invocation of that macro to start in an included file and complete in the main file, the model for `#include` would need to be similar to that for macro expansion: the whole text of the included file being inserted and then processed in the context of the surrounding preprocessing tokens.  But that is *not* the model.

Paragraph 5.1.1.2/1 describes the logical phases for translating C source code.  The relevant one here is phase 4 (emphasis added):

> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and `_Pragma` unary operator expressions are executed. If a
>    character sequence that matches the syntax of a universal character
>    name is produced by token concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is
>    undefined. **A `#include` preprocessing directive causes the named
>    header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4,
>    recursively.** All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

That `#include`ing a file causes *that file* to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4 means, among other things, that any function-like macro invocation that starts in that file must be complete within that file.  Preprocessing tokens following the `#include` directive are not relevant to the preprocessing of the included file.

And paragraph 6.10.3/10 says (in part):

> Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed by a
> `(` as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of
> preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the
> definition (an invocation of the macro).

That does not leave room to interpret the

> ```
> DECORATE(
> ```

in `macro_call.h` as anything other than the beginning of an invocation of `DECORATE()`, yet that cannot be processed because

> The replaced sequence of preprocessing tokens is terminated by the matching `)` preprocessing token

and in fact, paragraph 6.10.3/4 requires there to be such a token,
but no such preprocessing token appears in the file.